# Android Gradle - how to check if productFlavour is a debug or release

Tags: android, mobile, ant, build, gradle

I have a debug and release build type. I use also productFlavour with different configs. Now how do I check in productFlavour if that is a debug or a release build ?

```
signingConfigs {

        release {
            keyAlias '*****'
            keyPassword '****'
            storePassword '*****'
            storeFile file('./config/keystore/Android***ReleaseKeyStore')

        }

        unsigned{

        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug{
            runProguard false
            buildConfigField "String", "ID", "\"00000\""
            debuggable true**
        }

        release {

            runProguard true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-project.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlign true
            debuggable false
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        b2c {
            applicationId 'com.foo.bar'
            buildConfigField "String", "ID", "\"11111\""

            if(debuggable){
                  buildConfigField "String", "ID", "\"22222\""
            }
        }
```

...

Comment: "Now how do I check in productFlavour if that is a debug or a release build ?" -- you don't. Flavors are not debug or release builds. *Build variants* (combination of product flavor and build type) can be debug or release builds.

Comment: Yes, you say combination, but in debug I have a field ID which differs from debug and release. So when I do a build over all flavours which ID is used ? Like Debug + b2c ? Will it take 0000 or 1111 ?

Comment: "So when I do a build over all flavours which ID is used ?" -- whichever one you told it to use. If you use **`gradle assembleDebug`** to assemble all flavors, it will do a `debug` build. If you use **`gradle assembleRelease`** to assemble all flavors, it will do a `release` build.

Comment: did you find a solution? I want to solve the next task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677223/how-to-check-if-current-build-is-debug-or-release-in-build-gradle